# How do I delay 2 counters that are using the same clock signal?

Tags: clock, delay, synchronous

So we have this mod-16 counter with certain inputs and outputs:

[image]

[image]

[image]

We are with 2 sets of this counter supposed to realize a Mod-10 counter and Mod-2 counter. I think I know how to do that. The RCO (Ripple Carry Output) output looks like this:
$$RCO = q_d \wedge q_c \wedge q_b \wedge q_a \wedge T$$

So when the counter reaches fifteen and is about to go back to 0 RCO turns 1.

If we let the counters input be:

$$(1, \overline{RCO}, 1, 1, d, c, b, a)$$

We can see that we will count up to 15 and then load the number dcba (F in decimal)
When qd, qc, qb, qa = 1111 and T = 1, RCO = 1. We invert RCO to 0. Load will then invert it back to 1 and load the input number. So if we want a Mod-X counter we let F be:

$$F = 16 - X$$

So for a Mod-10 counter F in decimal is 16 - 10 = 6. As dcba = 0110. So we will count 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 6, 7, 8...

For a Mod-2 counter F in decimal is 16 - 2 = 14. As dcba = 1110. So we will count 14, 15, 14, 15...

Now we are given this task:

"*Realize a Mod-10 counter and a Mod-2 counter. Assume the counters are clocked with the 2Hz clock. How should they be connected to get two
output signals with the frequencies 1 and 0.1 Hz respectively? Note: The circuit should be synchronous, i.e using the same clock.*

I'm trying and struggling to figure out how one can delay the outputs in this way. We want the Mod-10 counter to have this frequency $$2Hz \times \frac {1}{2} = 1 Hz$$ and the Mod-2 counter $$2Hz \times \frac {1}{20} = 0.1 Hz$$

So the question remains. How do I delay these signals in this particular way? As you can see below we have standard gates at our disposal but also 6 D-elements. Can they be used in any way?

For context, this is the circuit board we have available:

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139759/discussion-on-question-by-felix9801-how-do-i-delay-2-counters-that-are-using-the).

Comment: @raoof are you sure that "respectively" applies to the counters, not the signals?

Answer (score 1):

Hint. 2Hz -> 1Hz = Divide by 2

Hint. 1Hz -> 0.1Hz = Divide by 10

Hint. The enable input to the counter can be used to prevent the counter from advancing its count even though the clock is running.

Comment: Right, at T = 0 state remains unchanged. Thanks for the tip!